# Display a non-mobile website with WebView in an Android app

Tags: java, javascript, android, webview

I'm currently working on a project at my university. The goal is to develop an Android app which functions as a mobile version of a website and its forum. I am currently asking myself if it is possible to display the website which doesn't have a view optimized for mobile devices in an Android app so that it looks like a mobile version of that site?

I stumbled upon WebView (WebKit) during my research and also read about JavaScript-Injection via WebView. Can somebody just plainly tell me if this would be a viable solution? Are there better alternatives i haven't come across? The only problem is the website doesn't have an API and i also don't have access to any data that isn't available to every user on the forum and the website.

Thanks in advance for your answers.

Answer (score 0):

You can checkout IBM Worklight and Apache Cordova

[link](http://www-03.ibm.com/software/products/en/worklight-foundation)
[link](http://cordova.apache.org/)

Comment: Cordova looks great, but i think it's the other way around isn't it? I want to develop the app in Java and modify the websites view to a mobile view. Do you think this is possible with Cordova?

Comment: @n1con Worklight has something called Hybrid Apps, basically you write your app in JAVA, HTML, CSS and Javascript. Checkout some of the modules for hybrid apps here. [link](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/mobile/worklight/getting-started.html) by the way, you can download worklight free of charge. Cordova has similar functionality for hybrid apps

Answer (score 0):

Try this it might work. Worked for me.

```
    webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    webView.getSettings().setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);
    webView.getSettings().setUseWideViewPort(true);

    webView.getSettings().setSupportZoom(true);
    webView.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
    webView.getSettings().setDisplayZoomControls(false);

    webView.setScrollBarStyle(WebView.SCROLLBARS_OUTSIDE_OVERLAY);
    webView.setScrollbarFadingEnabled(false);
```